# OpenCV SurfFeatureDetector heap corruption

Tags: c++, opencv, heap-corruption

I use this tiny code:

```
    Mat roulette_template = imread( "roulette_vorlage.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
    Mat greyMat = imread( "roulette_vorlage.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
    int minHessian = 400;
    SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );
    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;

    detector.detect( roulette_template, keypoints_1 );
    detector.detect( greyMat, keypoints_2 );
```

After detector.dectet the heap is corrupted. 
When I use this snippet in my other project it works fine.
Its called at the moment in my ProcessingCallback function which is called from my framegrabber.
I dont use any opencv function for getting the immage from my camera.

The entire code looks like that:

```
void PicoloVideo::ProcessingCallback2(PMCSIGNALINFO SigInfo)
{  
    switch(SigInfo->Signal)
    {
        case MC_SIG_SURFACE_PROCESSING:
            // Update "current" surface address pointer
            McGetParamInt (SigInfo->SignalInfo, MC_SurfaceAddr, (PINT32) &m_pCurrent); 


            // Post screen refresh message only if previous refresh completed
            if(m_bScreenRefreshCompleted)
            { 
                Mat roulette_template = imread( "roulette_vorlage.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );  
                Mat greyMat = imread( "roulette_vorlage.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
                int minHessian = 400;
                SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );
                std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;

                detector.detect( roulette_template, keypoints_1 );
                detector.detect( greyMat, keypoints_2 );

                if(waitKey(5) >= 0) break;
            }
            break;
        case MC_SIG_END_CHANNEL_ACTIVITY:
            m_bChannelActive = FALSE; 
            break;
        case MC_SIG_ACQUISITION_FAILURE:
            //MessageBox(NULL, "Acquisition Failure !", "PicoloVideo", MB_OK);
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
}
```

If have no idea why I get probs with the heap.
Anyone an idea why the detect stuff is killing it?

Comment: Post the stack trace please and/or the error you're getting (if informative at all)

Comment: Are you using the debug libraries in release configuration?

Comment: The information which I get are small: "program.exe": "C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\comctl32.dll" loaded, Cannot find or open the PDB file
HEAP[framegrabberWinapi.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 002F0000, 06EA5CF0 )

Comment: I run in debug and use the debug libs

Comment: I'm sorry for the n00b request but I've seen too many stupid errors in MSVC.. can you try cleaning the project and rebuilding from scratch?

Comment: @user3631353 - What you posted is not the stack trace.  The stack trace is the stack of all the `function calls` that lead to the error.  In there should be one of the functions `you're` calling.  Go to the `call stack` window, not the `Output` window.

Comment: The stacktrace is not really helpful: Framegrabber_CV.exe!PicoloVideo::ProcessingCallback2(_MC_CALLBACK_INFO * SigInfo)  Zeile 95 C++
  Framegrabber_CV.exe!ProcessingCallback(_MC_CALLBACK_INFO * SigInfo)  Zeile 56 C++
  MultiCam.dll!52053e5a()    
  MultiCam.dll!52076883()  
  MultiCam.dll!52076928()  
  kernel32.dll!769b33aa()  
  ntdll.dll!76f89ef2()  
  ntdll.dll!76f89ec5()

Comment: thats before the crash and after: ntdll.dll!770204e4()  
  ntdll.dll!76fe2a2a()  
  ntdll.dll!76fb1cd7()  
  MultiCam.dll!52076928()  
  kernel32.dll!769b33aa()  
  ntdll.dll!76f89ef2()  
  ntdll.dll!76f89ec5()

Comment: The thing is, the opencv stuff gets called from the callback function from my framegrabber. Because if I ran independend it works fine.